# Is there a term to denote the semantics of "the action of X"?

Tags: terminology, semantics

In English, the *-ing* form of verb performs multiple semantic functions; one of those functions is "the action of X".

In Japanese, the *-no* morpheme performs multiple semantic functions, and one of those functions is also "the action of X".

> 泳ぐ**の**は楽しい
>   oyogu-**no**-ha tanosi-i
>   swim-**NO**-TOP be.fun-PLAIN
>   "Swimming is fun"

Is there a good term for this semantic function of "the action of X" which can be used in comparative linguistics?

Comment: There is *gerund* in many languages, and also the more general *nomen actionis*, "noun of action", which is a noun denoting "the act/process of x-ing", created by adding an affix to a verbal stem.

Comment: Other languages suchs as Georgian and Mongolian use the term ***verbal noun***.

Comment: Thanks -- "gerund" to me felt like it has been corrupted too much by English education; it feels like a specific verb conjugation rather than a semantic concept. However the "nomen actionis"/"action noun"/"noun of action" stuff is not bad. "Verbal noun" sounds like a syntactic concept to me (even if it's the cast that anything with that syntax is only able to take on a single semantics, it still seems like the wrong way to say it).

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that what I'm really looking for is a good thing to call the semantic function of this -no in Japanese -- "actionizer" seemed wrong (that sounds like something which takes a noun and makes a verb, if anything). Maybe "action nominalizer" is the best I'm going to get...

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Don't worry, i thought it was totally clear you're looking for the semantic rather than the syntactic function of *-no* here. Syntactically, *-no* definitely seems to be some kind of nominaliser. *Action nominalizer* doesn't work as a description of its semantic function, really, since *noun* is an inherently syntactic notion - it has no status semantically.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie The example you give, assuming the translation is accurate, has a kind of *generic* meaning. It means something like *an event of someone swimming is generally a fun event*. I'm curious about whether these behave the same as gerunds in other respects, e.g. gerunds can refer directly to events: (i) *eating green beans was fun*. (i) can refer to a specific eating-green-beans event. Can you do this with a *no*-nominalisation? If so, they can be given the same neo-davidsonian analysis as gerunds, which i can lay out in an answer.

Comment: Gerund is no way a noun, it has verbal categories of voice (active/passive - writing vs. being written) and perfect/non-perfect (writing vs. having written and being written vs. having been written). Gerund is a verbal, an impersonal form of the verb.

Comment: @PElliott Indeed, it can refer directly to events as well: `サヤインゲンを食べるのは楽しかった` / `sayaingen-wo taberu-no-ha tanosi-katta` / `green.beans-ACC eat-NO-TOP be.fun-PAST` / `"Eating green beans was fun."` -- though as you mention these semantics are different.

Comment: @YellowSky If you can use an article with it, then in English it counts as a nominal! You can't say that these gerunds are purely verbal.

Comment: @curiousdannii - You cannot use articles before gerunds.